# Data Synchronization between Java EE and Windows Phone

Tags: jakarta-ee, windows-phone, data-synchronization

first of all I want to apologize if questions like the following aren't supposed to be asked here at SO but this is about my bachelor's thesis and I want to use every resource I can think of...

I am supposed to do a research about existing frameworks/tools that accomplish data synchronization between a Java EE application and Windows Phone. In case there are no existing solutions (which my employer doubts), I will probably try to implement something on my own using some general data synchronisation model (for example SAMD: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5331687&queryText%3Dsamd) and write my thesis about the pros and cons of that single approach, rather than comparing existing solutions.

So my question is: Do any of you guys know a solution that could be useful to me?

It's about data synchronisation in general but I'm thinking about making it more specific and focus on database snychonization. Moreover, as stated before, the focus lies on combining the Java EE and WP platforms (since this is what my employer is interested in) but it is not mandatory. For example if you know a framework that works with WP and some other platform that is not Java EE please go ahead and tell me about it. I will look into it and decide if it could be of any use to me. Take Microsoft's Sync Framework for example. I'm not sure if it can be combined with a Java EE application (can it?) but of course I'm looking into it...

Again, sorry that this is such a general question. Don't get me wrong, I'm not asking of you to do the research for me. I just thought that maybe someone already has had the same question at some point and can just give me pointer or anything.

Comment: maybe this question is suitable for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I also posted there.